# How to configure maps website in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, geotagging

I just discovered that Firefox supports the `geo` URI scheme: e.g. Brandenburg Gate (`geo:52.516272,13.377722`, perhaps SU's markdown doesn't support it).  It flashes up a blink-and-you'll-miss-it message "Redirecting to your selected maps website...".  For me, at least, that website seems to be qwant.com.

How can I select something else?  I expected it to be configured alongside my search engine in the "Search" section, but I can't see anything there, or even in about:config.

It would be really useful for me to be able to change it to a custom website.

Comment: geo uri is provided by an add-on, not firefox. Check the add-on configuration.

Comment: Damn, I must have forgotten I installed that!  Oops.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It would be more useful for you to post which add-on you're using and how to configure as an answer.  It's fine to answer your own question if it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had installed the [Geo URI Handler plugin](https://github.com/Andrew67/geo-handler) ages ago and forgotten about it.  This is unfortunately not a core feature of Firefox.  It can be configured by going to the addons manager `about:addons`, selecting Geo URI Handler, and in the preferences pane selecting a map from the drop-down list.